# Can't install Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation

I have watched three videos on installing dual-boot Ubuntu.  I downloaded the current iso 18.04 and verified the checksum.  When I boot it the "Try Ubuntu option works fine.  However, when I use "Install Ubuntu" I never get the screen asking about dual boot or something else.  Instead it immediately fails on "No / partition".  I have used Windows to shrink the C: partition leaving 100 GB unused.  How do I get the partitions in there?  Ubuntu install gives me no way to do it.

November 25:  After failing with "Disable fast boot" and "Disable secure boot" I booted with F12 and chose the "Change boot options".  I then enabled legacy boot which disabled UEFI boot.  The Ubuntu installation went further and said "do you want to use the whole disk since there is no OS on this machine".  I quit.  Windows 10 would not boot at all now.  Then through F12 I re-enabled UEFI boot and Windows 10 came back.  Apparently Dell has loaded my XPS 13 so it cannot use dual boot.  I may dedicate the whole machine to Linux.

In my opinion Ubuntu should stop claiming dual boot capability until its install program learns to deal with UEFI installed Windows.  My Dell XPS 13 is several years old, and Ubuntu install cannot deal with it even with all the obscure workarounds I have tried that have been suggested here.  Linus Torvalds said in 2016 that Linux distributions would just need to get a $99 key and learn to live with UEFI.  Apparently Ubuntu has not done this.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? UEFI or BIOS system and is Windows UEFI. Windows will be UEFI if pre-installed and Windows 8 or 10. You need to install in same boot mode as Windows UEFI or BIOS. If old BIOS you may have used all 4 primary partitions. Post this from live installer in question above: `sudo fdisk -lu`

Comment: Dell XPS 13 Laptop, Windows 10.  Partitions of Disk 0 are 500 mb healthy EFI 500 mb,  os c: 129 gb ntfs, 97.66 gb unallocated, winretools 852 mb ntfs, Image 10.38 gb ntfs

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Please don't pur new information such as output of `fdisk` in the comments. Copy and paste directly into the question above using the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1191199/edit) function. Then highlight the pasted text and format it as code by clicking on the { } icon above the edit question window.

Answer (score 1):

Boot up windows. Go to `Control Panel` > `Hardware and Sound` > `Power Options` > `System Settings` > `Choose what the power buttons do` and uncheck the `Turn on fast startup box`
Next, Disable `secureboot` in Windows from the BIOS Menu. Since it is different for every system, you can check out the laptop manual  to find how to get the BIOS Menu.
Then, boot from USB and check if you can get the option 'Something else' after 'Install Ubuntu'

Comment: I got to the BIOS and to my surprise, secure boot mode was already disabled.  I never found the fast startup box--only things about sleep times.  So no progress.

Comment: Fast boot is a setting in UEFI, fast start up is a setting Windows and is a hibernation setting for just operating system. Microsoft requires both as Windows boots so slow. Fast boot assumes no system changes, so you need it off when changing/reconfiguring system, so UEFI will rescan system and record changes for an operating system to use.

Comment: I finally successfully unchecked fastboot.  When installing from Ubuntu ISO I go through language choice, network startup, and download updates options.  Then continue brings up the screen "Installation Type".  The only choice in the dropdown is /dev/sda.  None of the other buttons work.  When I click continue, I get the popup "No root file system is defined".  I'm losing hope.